# Duplicate project reference in SSDT Database solution

Tags: visual-studio-2017, sql-server-data-tools

I am using tSQLt in a solution having multiple SQL Server Database projects in it. For each project, there is a .Test project which is referencing the original one and the tSQLt source.

Here is quick outline of the solution:

Solution

- Project `DB1`
- Project `DB1.Test`
- Project `DB2`
- Project `DB2.Test`
- Project `TSQLT`

Where

- Project `DB2` depends on Project `DB1`
- Project `DB1.Test` depends on `DB1` and `TSQLT` (using the 'Same database' option)
- Project `DB2.Test` depends on `DB2` and `TSQLT` (using the 'Same database' option) and on `DB1.Test` (Same server, different database with a variable). since `DB1.Test` depends on `DB1` and `TSQLT`, this project also depends on them (using the same variable used for `DB1.Test`).

The problem is that the reference to `DB1.Test` does not bring the `TSQLT` and `DB1` objects when it is referenced from `DB2.Test`, so I get a huge list of warnings about unresolved references.
Warnings related to `DB1` can be solved by referencing that project using the same variable as `DB1.Test`, but `TSQLT` is already referenced here and when I try to reference it twice, it leads to a "duplicate reference" error.

An obvious solution would be to make a copy of the TSQLT project in the solution, but honestly I just don't want to dupicate code.

Another would be to build that project using different configurations and simply reference the `.dacpac` files instead, but this feels like a hack.

We in theory could move the TSQLT project outside of the solution and have multiple copies of the `dacpac` file and reference those, however I am trying to keep everything in one place.

Currently we don't have NuGet repositories in place, so distributing code using NuGet packages to keep that part up-to-date does not work either.

I tried to reference it twice, but with different variable names, it still leads to the duplicate reference error.

I am aware, that unresolved reference errors in nested references scenario can be solved by adding all levels to the the project as a reference, but in this case one of the projects is used twice and duplicates are not allowed.

Is there any solution to either carry forward the references when there are nested references?

Or to have the local copy of the dacpac file generated during build saved using a custom (unique) name when it is copied from one project to another during build?

Please note that there are no circular references, just a project is used in multiple levels in the solution and without having the TSQLT reference in place for all instances, the build works just fine, just the warnings are annoying.

I am aware of the 'suppress warnings' option, but I would like to have them turned off. (This won't make the object magically appear in IntelliSense).

Turning the 'Local Copy' option on or off does not make any difference in behavior in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, which is still a bit smells like a hack, but working properly.

**Build event**

Add a post-build event to the common project:

1. Right click on the common project (TSQLT in this case)
2. Select `Properties...`
3. Go to the `Build Events` tab
4. Click on `Edit Post-build...`
5. Copy the following code into the editor window
6. Modify it to your needs
7. Save all when done (this will save the project and solution files)

   copy "$(ProjectName).dacpac" "$(ProjectName)_DB1.dacpac" /Y
   copy "$(ProjectName).dacpac" "$(ProjectName)_DB2.dacpac" /Y

This will create copies of the TSQLT.dacpac file in the output folder (`TSQLT_DB1.dacpac` and `TSQLT_DB2.dacpac` files will be created).

Make sure, that the build path for the dacpac file is using the `$(ProjectName)` variable, or use a hard-coded name and modify the build event accordingly.

**Database reference**

Reference these files as Data-tier application in the projects.

If you have multiple build configuration, open the .sqlproj file and edit it to have the build path dynamic:

```
<ArtifactReference Include="..\.build\$(Configuration)\TSQLT\TSQLT_DB1.dacpac">
  <HintPath>..\.build\$(Configuration)\TSQLT\TSQLT_DB1.dacpac</HintPath>
  <SuppressMissingDependenciesErrors>False</SuppressMissingDependenciesErrors>
  <DatabaseSqlCmdVariable>DB1</DatabaseSqlCmdVariable>
  <Private>False</Private>
</ArtifactReference>
<ArtifactReference Include="..\.build\$(Configuration)\TSQLT\TSQLT_DB2.dacpac">
  <HintPath>..\.build\$(Configuration)\TSQLT\TSQLT_DB2.dacpac</HintPath>
  <SuppressMissingDependenciesErrors>False</SuppressMissingDependenciesErrors>
  <DatabaseSqlCmdVariable>DB2</DatabaseSqlCmdVariable>
  <Private>False</Private>
</ArtifactReference>
```

Notice the `$(Configuration)` in the path. This method assumes, that the build configuration name is the same for all projects. (Basically we want the same thing here what you have in the build path(

Now you can remove the original project reference.

**Build dependency**

By removing the project reference, Visual Studio also removes the build dependency.

1. Right click on the solution
2. Select `properties...`
3. Go to `Common Properties` / `Project Dependencies`
4. Select the project from the drop-down list
5. Tick the checkbox in front of the referenced project

This ensures that building the current project will trigger the build of the referenced one (and that will run the post-build event).

**Notes**

I did update all projects in the solution which are using TSQLT to have artifact reference instead of project reference, this keeps the solution more consistent.

I did not change the reference to other projects, since I don't have this kind of issue with them.